# Function not getting called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Following is my javascript code. The problem is when I call the `send()` function it doesnt really respond because x, y and z because they are local variables. I have tried making them global using a few approaches like creating an object but all have failed. Anybody here knows a proper approach to do that?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function store(x,y,z) {           
      var date = x+" "+y+" "+z;
      document.getElementById("date").value=date;
  }
  function send(){
      var events=document.getElementById("event").value;
      location.href="q.php?day=" + x + "&month=" + y + "&year=" + z;        
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Would appreciate if you could post more code. How you define the variables. And how you call the function. Best from Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, considering you are calling `store` function before `send`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var xx, yy, zz; //These are your global variables
   function store(x,y,z) {   
      xx = x;
      yy = y;
      zz = z;          
      var date = x + " " + y + " " + z;
      document.getElementById("date").value = date;
   }

   function send(){
      var events = document.getElementById("event").value;
      location.href="q.php?day=" + xx + "&month=" + yy + "&year=" + zz;      
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the URL in the `store` function, then you only need one global variable:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  var url;

  function store(x, y, z) {           
    var date = x + " " + y + " " + z;
    document.getElementById("date").value = date;
    url = "q.php?day=" + x + "&month=" + y + "&year=" + z;
  }

  function send(){
    var events = document.getElementById("event").value;
    location.href = url;
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the name of function send and store

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var xGlobal,yGlobal,zGlobal;
    function mystore(x,y,z) {      
        xGlobal=x;
        yGlobal=y;
        zGlobal=z;       
        var date = x+" "+y+" "+z;

        document.getElementById("date").value=date;
    }

    function mysend(){
        var events=document.getElementById("event").value;
        location.href="q.php?day=" + xGlobal + "&month=" + yGlobal + "&year=" + zGlobal;      
    }
</script>
```

see [the example in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hemant1027/JwMpJ/)